# Forcing cache refresh after modifying head.js javascript calls?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, head.js

I am using head.js and using the below file to initiate the javascript file calls:

```
 <script src="/scripts/load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the load.js file I have the following code:

```
head.js(

   {livechat: "/scripts/livechat.js"},
   {jquery: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"},
   {jquerytools: "http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"},
   {slider: "/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"},
   {prettyphoto: "/scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"},
   {sliderfunctions: "/scripts/slidercode.js"},
   {functions: "/scripts/functions.js"}

);
```

My problem is, even though I removed the livechat line, the chat box is still appearing on all my website pages unless I manually clear the browser cache. My concern is that I no longer utilize the livechat service and I do not want the visitors to be confused by seeing the livechat box appear but not function correctly.

Is there any way to tell head.js that there has been a change in the files being loaded and to refresh browser cache or something?

Answer (score 2):

You could put something along the lines of this:

```
<script src="/scripts/load.js?date=123456789" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Adding a query string to this file should trick the browser into thinking it's something it hasn't seen before.